# Few questions about objects in JAVA

Tags: java, object, constructor

I am quite new to programming and my assignment this week is based around objects in java.

Before anything here are my codes

```
public class Animal {
float mass;
String name;
int legs;

// Exercise 6-6
public Animal(String randomName) {
    name = randomName;
    legs = 0;
    mass = 0;
}

// Exercise 6-7
public Animal(float one, String two, int three) {
    mass = one;
    name = two;
    legs = three;
}

//Exercise 7
public String toString(){
    return "name =" + name + "legs=" + legs + "mass=" + mass;
}

public void massSetter() {

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getLegs() {
    return legs;
}
}
```

Then there is this one

```
public class Zoo {
private Animal[] park;

// Exercise 9
public Zoo() {
    Animal[] park = new Animal[10];
}

// Exercise 10
public void addAnimal(Animal first) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (park[i] != null) {
            park[i] = first;
            i = 10;
        } else if (i == 9) {
            System.out.println("The zoo is full!");
        }

    }
}

// Exercise 11
public void feed() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        park[i].mass *= 1.1;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return "The zoo is capable of keeping " + park.length + "animals"
            + '\n'
            + "The following is the list of animals currently in the zoo."
            + '\n' + "cage 1 status: " + park[0] + '\n' + "cage 2 status: "
            + park[1] + '\n' + "cage 3 status: " + park[2] + '\n'
            + "cage 4 status: " + park[3] + '\n' + "cage 5 status: "
            + park[4] + '\n' + "cage 6 status: " + park[5] + '\n'
            + "cage 7 status: " + park[6] + '\n' + "cage 8 status: "
            + park[7] + '\n' + "cage 9 status: " + park[8] + '\n'
            + "cage 10 status: " + park[9];
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println(park.toString());
}

public int totalLegs() {
    int totalLeg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        totalLeg += park[i].legs;
    }
    return totalLeg;
}
}
```

and finally

```
public class TestZoo {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Zoo zoo = new Zoo();

}
}
```

I have two questions.

First of all as you can see from the toString method in Zoo class, my return statement is way too long. I tried using for loop but i seems i cant really do that in a return statement so I was wondering if there is any simpler way.

The second question is that the exercise tells me to fill up the object zoo that I made in the TestZoo class with names like elephant and spider. I was wondering how i could do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all as you can see from the toString method in Zoo class, my return statement is way too long. I tried using for loop but i seems i cant really do that in a return statement so I was wondering if there is any simpler way.

```
public String toString() {
    String str = "The zoo is capable of keeping " + park.length + "animals\nThe following is the list of animals currently in the zoo.";
    for(int i = 0; i < park.length; i++)
        str += '\n' + "cage " + i + " status: " + park[i];

    return str;

}
```

> The second question is that the exercise tells me to fill up the object zoo that I made in the TestZoo class with names like elephant and spider. I was wondering how i could do this.

```
public class TestZoo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
        Animal spider = new Animal("spider");
        zoo.addAnimal(spider);
    }
}
```

If you've got a lot of animals, the above method won't actually be feasible. So create an array of `String`s (Strings because you need one to make an Animal)

```
String[] arr = {"Spider", "Elephant"};
```

And then add create an animal for each of the string, and add the animal

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    Animal a = new Animal( arr[0] );
    zoo.addAnimal(a);
}
```

OR just

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    zoo.addAnimal(new Animal(arr[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use `StringBuilder` and loop to build a string. See docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html).
2) You have method `addAnimal(Animal first)` for adding animal to zoo.

Answer (score 0):

1. The toString is like any other method. You can create variables.

   String value = "The zoo is capable of keeping " + park.length + "animals";
   value =value  + '\n'; // etc
   return value;
2. Somthing like

   zoo.add(new Animal("zebra"));

Comment: Doesn't suggest anything to address the manual indexing of the arrays in the `toString` method.

Answer (score 0):

For your `toString()`:   Use a `StringBuilder` with a for-loop in conjuction with [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead to greatly reduce the length.

The loop is important since you're basically echoing the contents of the entire array.  Be sure that `Animal` has overridden `toString()` to provide valuable information about the instance.

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder("The zoo is capable of keeping " + park.length + "animals");
    ret.append("\n");
    ret.append("The following is the list of animals currently in the zoo.");

    for(int i = 0; i < park.length; i++) {
        ret.append(String.format("\ncage %d status : " + park[i].toString()));
    }
    return ret.toString();
}
```

To fill your zoo, given the constructor for `Animal`, I would presume that passing the name "spider" would suffice.

```
Animal spider = new Animal("spider");
Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
zoo.addAnimal(spider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: ...return statement is too long...no way to do that in a return statement
A: do it separately. Build the display String (or StringBuilder) in a loop, then return the result.

Q2: ...fill up the object zoo
A: you'll need to create new animals and call addAnimal once for each.
An initialized array of animal names and a for-loop might help:
String names[]= {"aardvark", "bison", "cat", "dog", "eagle", "elephant", "giraffe", "horse", "owl", "emu"};

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String result = "The list:\n";
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    result = result + "cage " + i + " status:" + park[i] + "\n"; 
}
return result;
```

Here "+" concatenates adjacent strings, and you build up the total result one line at a time.

But using string concatenation is somewhat inefficient (though perfectly adequate for `toString` in most cases, since that's usually for diagnostics), so many times it's better to use something like StringBuilder, especially for main-line "production" methods.